# GIt integration for Coda app

Tags: git, coda

Anyone can recommend a solution for this?

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know, Panic has not announced any specific plans to include support for Git in Coda, but it seems unlikely that it won't make it into the app at some point.

For now, there are two Git GUIs for OS X (not including gitk): GitX and Gity. Both have plugins for Coda, but it's not quite the direct integration you might be looking for. Check out the two apps and their respectively plugins here:

[Git For Coda](http://justinhileman.info/git-for-coda)

Comment: Thank you so much Jimmy, not only for the Coda tie in but introducing me to Gity, I just didn't like GitX and sometimes I get bored looking at a terminal window all day!

Answer (score 6):

git is now integrated into [Coda 2](http://panic.com/coda/).

Answer (score 3):

Been using this >> http://www.git-tower.com/

Comment: how have you been using it with coda?

Answer (score 2):

Since we have not seen any official Git integration with Coda we have been using this third party Git tool which we simply love. It's a bit pricey for only a Git client, but blows away GitX or GitY, is beautiful and great to use. It's worth giving it a test drive.

Tower - http://www.git-tower.com/

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Gity and the [Coda plugin for Gity](http://github.com/downloads/bobthecow/Gity.codaplugin/Gity.codaplugin.zip) and they're not bad...

But I suggest you all with GIT/MAC/CODA troubles to take a look at the *new Git Mac App*: [Git Tower](http://www.git-tower.com).

Still in beta, but... Enjoy! :)

Comment: Now you can get the benefits of Git Tower with the comfort of a Coda plugin via [Tower.codaplugin](https://github.com/daschae/Tower.codaplugin).